# Safety of Quick-Pickles at Room Temperature

Tags: food-safety, pickles

I just followed a recipe for pickled turnips, but am questioning the step of letting them sit out at room temp for 5 days before refrigerating.

The recipe used:
1 cup white vinegar (5% acidity)
3 cups water
70 grams salt

It's a 1:3 vinegar to water ratio and, if my math is right, has a salinity level of about 7.5% (by weight).

I have found this same, or nearly the same, recipe on several websites so it seems to be pretty standard, but just wanted to ask about the safety of skipping refrigeration for nearly a week.

Comment: I was curious I've peruse a few recipes, some say to leave it at room temp for few days , some say to refrigerate immediately; personally, I put in the fridge as soon as it is at room temperature.